# Create EXE that mounts virtual CD-ROM or floppy disk when run

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, disk-image

I was looking through my old USB drives and I found a flash drive that had a file called "SecretDrive.exe." When I ran it, it mounted a virtual floppy disk that contained stoke other files.  There didn't seem to any image file that came with this EXE. What I was wondering was if there is any way to create an EXE like this that does this.

Comment: Are you sure it was a virtual floppy? Did the program throw up any UAC dialogs or install a driver? Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Note that you cannot right information to resources stored inside an EXE. the extra data had to be going somewhere on disk.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1. There were no UAC dialogs,  and I'm sure it was a floppy drive that showed up.  It was that A drive and had the Windows floppy drive icon.  The data was read Only of course.

Comment: is this the program? http://www.iodata.com/en/products/download/en/secretdrive.htm

Comment: Yeah. Is there any way to do this without buying one of those drives?